# Quasinilpotent operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$. How to prove that:
If $\lambda \pi(I)-\pi(T)$ is invertible in the Calkin algebra $C(X)$, then $\pi(T)$ is quasinilpotent in $C(X)$.
Where, $\pi$ is the (canonical) quotient map of the set of bounded linear operators on $X$ onto $C(X)$.

Definition : an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ is said to be a quasinilpotent if the spectral radius $r(T)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\|T^{n}|| ^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$.

Comment: What is $\lambda $?

Comment: This question is weirdly phrased. Assuming that is says "for every nonzero $\lambda$", then the result has nothing to do with the Calkin algebra, as neither the hypothesis nor the conclusion deal with $T$, only with $\pi(T)$. And if the spectral radius is known to be the spectral radius, then the result follows by definition, there's nothing to be proven.

Comment: For $\lambda \neq 0$, if $\lambda  \pi(I) -\pi(T)$ is invertible in the calkin algebra, this immediately implise that $\pi(T)$ is quasinilpotent ?. @Martin Argerami, Ruy.

Comment: In another form, if $\lambda \pi(I) -\pi(T)$ is invertible in the calkin algebra $C(X)$ ($\lambda  \in \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$), do we have $\pi(T)$ with empty spectrum ?.

Comment: No, you have that the spectrum is $\{0\}  $. Unless you are doing real algebras, the spectrum is never empty.

Comment: Please Mr.@Martin Argerami, see the proof of Corollary 3.2.9 page 39 in the book "S.R. Caradus, W.E. Pfaffenberger and B. Yood Calkin Algebras and Algebras of Operators on Banach Spaces, Marcel Dekker, 1974.". Thanks.